# Type-safe iteration over array or object

Tags: typescript

I have a generic iteration method that can be passed objects or arrays but I'm having trouble getting the type checks to work.

[Here's what I have so far](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBJOIYENsCCMA5ggLwIDeA2gNYjIBcAznDAJYB2xAuo7p2QBfAD4Dk1HgG5goSLEQo0mbHmwBpBgB4AKgnDZOAE2Yqc+EEWIA+cgj0GQx0+MkIA-Ak4BXALYAjHARGBHpkKAAzexlZcGh4BABjKE5WBHZVCztdVHRHZzM1SxJrAAoofwArAH1YatwYPCZ7XIAaJNwAG07-XETaENKANy7vEH5BVrCQrHMNbR1c2wBKMmtxZfJbSlkASHYo0oQiJoA6dmYT3GRyqtqYesbr5c2d3d2KmrqGs4jYAFE+gALUqJLo9Pq0ZYxXbAXZCECdZggHZw3Z-GAIYYNUIMdKcBCfe6PJqvNH7Q5E75PZCnIG4ZgAeQA7pwAAowKBoeA3MIvKjk3Zg7q9fq3L4PH7XOgMHjtPkyd7wtFCOGq2FCGIRbycRJwdgpBBS5AAYXBoto2M6YxYbC4xHlDEYPgCOGWlFVwAycxApWoAHJcP7Wv7-P65cazSLIdDZNrdfrDZ8QHqoxCxSNreNWBxuI6mDn7e7Pd6iqVKLhGIHg-4q2GhK1k6nzTGpEA)

```
export type IterateArg = {[key:string]:any}|any[];

export type IterateKey<T extends IterateArg> = T extends any[] ? number : keyof T;


export const iterate = <Type extends IterateArg>(obj_or_array: Type, callback: (value:any,key: IterateKey<Type> )=>any) => {

    if ( Array.isArray(obj_or_array)) {
        obj_or_array.forEach(callback); // error #1

    
    }else{

        for (var key in obj_or_array) {
            if (obj_or_array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                callback(obj_or_array[key], key); // error #2
            }
        }
    }
    
};

function arrayCallback(value:string, key:number){}

iterate(['a','b'],arrayCallback);

function objectCallback(value:string, key:string){}

iterate({a:'a',b:'b'},objectCallback);
```

**Errors**

1. Argument of type '(value: any, key: IterateKey) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number, array: any[]) => void'.
   Types of parameters 'key' and 'index' are incompatible.
   Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'IterateKey'.
2. Argument of type 'Extract<keyof Type, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IterateKey'.
   Type 'string & keyof Type' is not assignable to type 'IterateKey'.

Comment: Just added the errors. They are a bit more readable in the linked TypeScript playground though

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NleRrm) where you explicitly write a type guard function to distinguish your two desired call signatures.  It's about as safe as I can make it; the compiler doesn't treat arrays as discriminants so narrowing `obj_or_array` to `any[]` by itself has no effect on `callback`.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Interesting, that looks like it does the trick! Wish it could be cleaner ([my tinkering has only broken things](https://tsplay.dev/WGRlKm)) but beggars can't be choosers. Thanks so much!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found anything which is both clean and type safe.  It's easy enough to throw [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) at the problem, like

```
export const iterateOrig = <Type extends IterateArg>(
    obj_or_array: Type, callback: (value: any, key: IterateKey<Type>) => any
) => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj_or_array)) {
        obj_or_array.forEach(callback as (value: any, key: number) => any); // okay
    } else {
        for (var key in obj_or_array) {
            if (obj_or_array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                callback(obj_or_array[key], key as any); // okay
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and move on.  If you want to try to get a little more safety, then you need to refactor to something a big less clean looking.

---

The first problem you're running into is that TypeScript cannot use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on the  [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter you're calling `Type`.  If you check `Array.isArray(obj_or_array)`, it narrows the type of `obj_or_array`, but stubbornly leaves `Type` as `Type extends IterateArg`.  This is a known limitation or missing feature of TypeScript, discussed in GitHub issues [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) and [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) among others.  It's not a trivial thing to solve, because technically `Type` might actually be the full `IterateArg` [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), and then `IterateKey<Type>` will itself be a union, and narrowing behaves oddly in such circumstances.  Ideally you'd like to tell the compiler that `Type` could *either* be the object-thing *or* the array-thing, *but not* the union of both.  And that's not part of the language yet.

---

So generics aren't really helping you much.  We can refactor instead so that the function takes a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) that is union of a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#rest-parameters-with-tuple-types) so that you can call it either with an array-and-associated-callback or a non-array-object-and-associated-callback, like this:

```
export const iterate = (...args:
    [arr: any[], callback: (value: any, key: number) => any] |
    [obj: { [key: string]: any, forEach?: never }, callback: (value: any, key: string) => any]
) => { }
```

Note that without direct support for *negated types* as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) there's no perfectly accurate type corresponding to "an object that is not an array".  Instead I just used "an object without a defined `forEach` property" (or rather, an object with an [optional property](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type)) and figure that's close enough.  If you find yourself wanting to pass in a non-array with a `forEach` property then ‍♂️ you can change it to `{lastIndexOf?: never}` or something else.

Let's make sure that this is still callable the way we want:

```
function arrayCallback(value: string, key: number) { }
function objectCallback(value: string, key: string) { }

iterate(['a', 'b'], arrayCallback); // okay
iterate({ a: 'a', b: 'b' }, objectCallback); // okay
iterate(['a, b'], objectCallback) // error
iterate({ a: 'a', b: 'b' }, arrayCallback); // error
```

---

Now for the implementation, where we hit pretty much the same problem you had before:

```
export const iterateOops = (...args:
    [arr: any[], callback: (value: any, key: number) => any] |
    [obj: { [key: string]: any, forEach?: never }, callback: (value: any, key: string) => any]
) => {
    const [obj_or_array, callback] = args;
    if (Array.isArray(obj_or_array)) {
        obj_or_array.forEach(callback); // error
    } else {
        for (var key in obj_or_array) {
            if (obj_or_array.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                callback(obj_or_array[key], key); // error
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*Now* the issue is the compiler does not perceive the `args` variable to be a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) because the first element (`obj_or_array`) is not a *discriminant* property.  TypeScript only sees types including [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) to be valid discriminants, and `IterateArg` doesn't include literal types.

That means we need to write our own user-defined [type predicate function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) that takes `args` and narrows it to either the array-and-callback or the non-array-and-callback pair.  Here's one way to write that:

```
function firstElemIsArray(arg: any[]): arg is [any[], ...any[]] {
    return Array.isArray(arg[0]);
}
```

And now we have to refactor to use that before destructuring `args`:

```
export const iterate = (...args:
    [arr: any[], callback: (value: any, key: number) => any] |
    [obj: { [key: string]: any, forEach?: never }, callback: (value: any, key: string) => any]
) => {
    if (firstElemIsArray(args)) {
        const arr = args[0];
        const callback = args[1]
        arr.forEach(callback);
    } else {
        const obj = args[0];
        const callback = args[1];
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                callback(obj[key], key);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This all compiles without error, and is hopefully a little more type safe.  Implementations of user-defined type guard functions with type predicates are not strictly checked (you could change the body to just `return Math.random() < 0.5` and the compiler wouldn't notice) so that's the only place where you need to be careful.

Personally if you're confident nobody's going to misuse the function and that your implementation logic is reasonable, then you could just go with type assertions as shown at the top.  It's up to you, though.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBJOIYENsCCMA5ggLwIDeCA2gNYjIBcCAznDAJYB2xAui1zdkCAL4IAPgiHIafANzBQkWIhRpM2PNgDSjADwAVBOGzcAJq0058IIsQB85BMdMgLVmXIQB+BNwBXAFsAIxwEFgZkKAAzF0UlcGh4BABjKG52BE4tWwB5LlIKI1R0Nw9rbTsSBwAKYABIKBCAKwB9WDbcGDxmF1KAGjTcABsRkNxUuhZagDdRgJBBYSGoliwbXQNDUocASnInGWADsidKRs442qJegDpOVlvcZFrm9s7u3r2Di4am1odGBdHovO4xWAAUUmAAtaqlRuNJnRpFY5gsltIVgg1v5gmEYKcjsI9vIEAB6ckIKB0F6NcQgEasdB-BoQmAIdEcqLZbjUwGfUHIX6Nf5XTnvIEg+4w3CsPIAd24AAUYFA0PBXlEflRRf8EWMJlM3gLgV8XvRGHxVoxUVjhWTKdTacg9aJRe6Gu7RAllMlEOlMogcpsQHl1VYKLU7jHusRWExGjQvstZNbhobkTN5iNFqmbX1AqEcET7XxJEn3ixqJa+uwuLwBPahuzoakYT4WNwQLNwqIhgakVNsxj8zjGCx6zxiKWZHwToddQ1A1kaJLBb0B4ijXRyxQ46xFA1xTchQ8nkKTR8zUKdaz1zf7q3YfDt8jSRSqTg1TB6SYmSyorspy8zcraPD8te0ovCK-zHtcD7QcgdyyvKSqquqOAoLU2qwXBg47leUrmrIUTptqjpfj0sBuh69LAD6SjADEATcKkcCcBkCAxJwMDsJCIwgEEGAXr0tRxqmch7IIJDZFYybCHIQwxncXh8OWfwwCAcABDAfLPMhjwGeJJA0AADHwpIMUxSSqGkGRZCGVTONGsYkAmSYpvaSkZkO0wgaOzbjoW+Ilouc4Vg0a6tNWtC4lOjZjs+7adv4PZ9lumbDgFuaYjIBaThw06zsI86ln8J48XxcACUJInGQed6iiuiBfM4B7mQozUOQGb5TO17k0AAjPO-xfOCUIvgR75HgyAFLsuPWQQN8adUei1Br5O4raww1df8wFcsFvKQXh8ESq0KFyoqKpqhq2G4Qt+p9XQV61uRjBWXBnpevRjHMax7GcXyJEAMIveiuWFQ2xAFXixaElQYgA2xHFce8IDseDWWvTmeZsEVvBwwlM5I+6wBObYtQ0AA5LgNNDDTIQ0+mYMvR+To0nSlPYLU1C4CwdMMwgISC8zYhDBjWPs5Rzrc7kvO07gQzM+mUtwNjfkHE6340TzIB89Igv0yrYs0xL0hCprO4c1RP5AA)

Comment: Thanks for solution and thorough explanation!